# How do I make an apps script that will automatically input a timestamp when a cell is updated to certain criteria?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have included a test sheet to make this easier:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XnKnj0lkLmWrs1GcQRBUc_HKd-WEajlKmsX_Rlj-fqI/edit?usp=sharing

What I would like to have happen is, when I select the option "Started" from the dropdown in column D, it automatically populates column F in the same row with the current time and date. And preferably makes this uneditable. Then when the dropdown in column D is changed to "Completed", it populates another timestamp in column G, which should likewise make it uneditable.

I have tried various combinations of code, but can't find the right one. I'm not very experienced with javascript and I don't know how to write it on my own.

Comment: You probably want to use an onEdit trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).

> Triggers let Apps Script run a function automatically when a certain
> event, like editing a cell, occurs.

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  if(row > 1 && col == 4){
    var selected = e.value;
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy-HH:mm:ss");
    var sh = e.range.getSheet();
    var colEdit = 0;
    if(selected == "Started"){
      colEdit = parseFloat(col+2);
    }else{
      colEdit = parseFloat(col+3);
    }
    var editedRange = sh.getRange(row,parseInt(colEdit),1,1);
    editedRange.setValue(date);
    
    //Optional: Uncomment the code below if you want to add protection to the cell    
    //This will make the cell uneditable to the other users.
    //editedRange.protect();
  } 
}
```

Note: Since you are the owner of the spreadsheet, you cannot make the cell uneditable. But you can add [Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) to make it uneditable to others.

**Output:**
[image]